# Video and audio continuous recording

Tags: audio, video, video-streaming, recording

I need to develope an application which can make a continuous recording of some video or audio streams.

Other than record, the application should:

- let the user see the recordings selecting a stream and a date/time
- cut some part of recordings regarding to some schedules
- let the user cut a piece of recording selecting using the web interface

My doubt is how to record and save the piece of videos. I don't want to wait the file to be closed to let the user play it, so I would use a progressive file type.

The application must work on Linux.

Could you help me, please?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I think you need to be a lot more specific in order to get help here. How are you trying to program this, and what problems are you encountering?

Comment: I will record channels using some Linux DVB dump programs (this is not a problem), the problem is about how to manage and index video recordings files on a continuous recording system (for example use 10 minutes chunks, or something like this).